# Is there way to install ICS on Galaxy Pocket?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, installation, samsung-galaxy-pocket

I have Samsung Galaxy Pocket - GT-S5300.

Is there a way to install ICS and it will work properly? Will overclock be needed?

If so, how to do so?

Comment: Take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575). The answers list most available sources, so if there's any ICS ROM available for your device, you should find it there.

Answer (score 1):

This device will never officially get ICS, as it only has an Armv6 processor. ICS needs an armv7 processor to function.

The only way to get ICS would be if someone ports it to your device - but it would be difficult. I suggest you look at [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com) to see if someone has ported it, or is trying to.

Be aware that it would be buggy if it is ported.